# jQuery pass dynamic id value to function

Tags: jquery

Im new at JS/jQuery.

I got this code:

```
<button id="value1" class="buttonkontakte" onclick="kontakte()">KLICK1</button>
<button id="value2" class="buttonkontakte" onclick="kontakte()">KLICK2</button>
<button id="value3" class="buttonkontakte" onclick="kontakte()">KLICK3</button>
```

jQuery:

```
function kontakte(){
    var getthevalue = ???????????????;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {wasmachen: "kontakte", value: getthevalue},
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#kontakte').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Now when I click on KLICK1 I want to pass "value1" to the var getthevalue. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple pass `this` inside the html `onclick` to know Who called the function like:

```
<button id="value1" class="buttonkontakte" onclick="kontakte(this)">KLICK1</button>
<button id="value2" class="buttonkontakte" onclick="kontakte(this)">KLICK2</button>
<button id="value3" class="buttonkontakte" onclick="kontakte(this)">KLICK3</button>
```

And the function get the value like:

```
function kontakte(e){
    var getthevalue = $(e).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {wasmachen: "kontakte", value: getthevalue},
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#kontakte').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me what (e) is exactly doing?

Comment: `e` is the event object that is passed to the function kontakte(). In this exameple I uses `e` but could be whaterver you want. And in the HTML you need pass this to know what event object is calling the click.

Comment: Thanks :) JS is really complicated compared to PHP

Answer (score 2):

Please get rid of those ugly inline javascript event handlers

```
$('.buttonkontakte').click(function(){
  value=$(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {wasmachen: "kontakte", value: value},
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#kontakte').html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, moreover `id` is a property of the dom element, you can use `this.id` directly..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thats true, I also forgot to enclose id in quotes but now edited

Comment: The result is "undefined" :( is it because the buttons are generated inside the post.php?

Comment: its more likely the php is not returning what you expect on  the ajax request.  hit f12 and check your browser network tab to see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by handling the click with jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Start of the block of jQuery code

    // Define a function which needs a parameter
    function kontakte(getthevalue) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: {wasmachen: "kontakte", value: getthevalue},
            success: function(msg) {
            $('#kontakte').html(msg);
        }
        });
    }

    // Handling the on click event via jQuery instead of HTML
    $("#value1").click(function() {
        // Call your function with a parameter now.
        kontakte("value1");

        // Or if you want the passed value to be the same as the id of your button
        var value = $(this).attr('id');
        kontakte(value);
    }

} // end jQuery
```

Your HTML will look like:

```
<button id="value1" class="buttonkontakte">KLICK1</button>
<button id="value2" class="buttonkontakte">KLICK2</button>
<button id="value3" class="buttonkontakte">KLICK3</button>
```

With this, you will handle everything in jQuery since, as far as I am concerned, you cannot call a function in the **onclick** attribute when the function is declared inside a jQuery block. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thats pretty good too, but I need it to be refreshed every sec because it's for a chat. But I learned something new with that too :)